# How to convert from an array to an associative container?

Tags: c++, arrays, containers, associative-array

I have an array of characters in which I have stored alternating keys and values sequentially. What is a suitable container for storing key/value pairs, and how can I go about moving the contents of my array into this container?

Comment: Std::map. Include <map>

Comment: Did you even consider doing any research?

Answer (score 1):

At present the C++ Standard suggests the following associative containers:

1. Ordered associative containers: `std::map`, `std::multimap`, `std::set`, `std::multiset`
2. Unordered associative containers:  `std::unorderd_map`, `std::unordered_multimap`, `std::unordered_set`, `std::unordered_multiset`

I think that the more appropriate container for you is either `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 0):

See Standard Library *map*:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

High level languages hide it, but since arrays are primitive storage formats, associative arrays are not, don't forget!

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: split string into array of key-value strings. Split each of them into key and value and put to a map.

Method 2: parse string char by char, and keep track of what state the parsing is in: between key-value pairs, parsing key, between key and value, parsing value. When ever state changes away from parsing value, add last key and value to map.

Latter method is useful if keys and values can have escape chars, in which case you have a few more states, for example: after escape char in key, after escape char in value.